# How do I drop the first character in a string for many columns at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 6 columns that are objects ($19.99, $25.99, etc.) that I want to turn into floats (19.99, 25.99, etc.). The first thing I must do is drop the first character for all of these columns. I was able to do it doing this.

```
df['Subtotal_'] = df['Subtotal'].str[1:]
df['Shipping Charge_'] = df['Shipping Charge_'].str[1:]
df['Tax Before Promotions_'] = df['Tax Before Promotions_'].str[1:]
df['Total Promotions_'] = df['Total Promotions_'].str[1:]
df['Tax Charged_'] = df['Tax Charged_'].str[1:]
df['Total Charged_'] = df['Total Charged_'].str[1:]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do them all at once. I tried this but it didn't work and I got the error, "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'".

```
df[['Subtotal_', 'Shipping Charge_', 'Tax Before Promotions_',
    'Total Promotions_', 'Tax Charged_', 'Total Charged_']] = df.loc[:, 'Subtotal':'Total Charged'].str[1:]
```

Comment: What is ".str[1:]" for ? as you may expect float or int, it may be the problem. 
Please show a working piece of code and data you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give more specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cols = ('Subtotal_', 'Shipping Charge_', 'Tax Before Promotions_', 'Total Promotions_', 'Tax Charged_', 'Total Charged_')
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str[1:]
```

Comment: `df[col][1:]` should be `df[col].str[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.loc[:, list_of_the_columns_to_change] = df[same_list].replace('^\$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider accept my answer if you liked it. Happy coding!

Comment: It's better to avoid regexp if possible. It can add problems sometimes

Comment: I edited my answer, so it just replace `$` if it's in the start of a string.